# Custom order revolution sliders post base slides as inserted in Specific Posts List field

Tags: wp-query, customization, order

My homepage shows about 10-20 post that are manually selected in a slide.
I have used Revolution slider. There is a field  `Specific Posts List field` Where I have inserted post Ids `16427,16557,16822,16392,16507` and I want to show them as I have inserted on the field.

I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/245555/revolution-slider-orderby-two-custom-fields) Helpful in understanding but I don't want to insert a "order" custom field if possible. [Another link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters) made me understand what other option I have however don't understand `post__in` and `menu_order`.

**Is there a way to show it as my custom list without using custom field?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function modify_slider_order($query, $slider_id) {

    if($slider_id == 4) {
       // $ids=[16427,16557,16822,16507,16392,16548,16564,16426,16412,16404,16419,16421];
         $query['orderby'] = 'post__in';
//         $query['orderby'] = array (
//     'post__in' => $ids,
//     'orderby' => 'post__in',
//     'order'   => 'ASC'
// );


    }

    return $query;

}

add_filter('revslider_get_posts', 'modify_slider_order', 10, 2);
```

This solved my problem, I'm not sure why I don't even have to pass IDs but this worked.